# jQuery ajaxSubmit() API issue with 'iframe: true'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to make an ajax call and target the response to an iFrame.

Here's the piece of code:

```
function getResponse(requestData) {
    $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
            type: "POST",
            url: "servlet/myServletPath",
            data: {requestData: requestData},
            timeout: 10000000,
            iframe: true
    });
```

}

This works just fine except my servlet can't find any parameter with the name 'requestData'. The same starts working when I remove 'iframe: true'. But I need to post my response to an iframe.

Any idea what exactly is happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried using GET instead of POST. It worked just fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

you will get your response to success function if succeded so add a success function

```
 success: function (response) 
            {
                // Perform your process after succeeding 
                iframe: true                
            },
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                alert(error);
            }
```

Comment: ```iframe:true``` is a property of the ```ajaxSubmit``` object, why have you put it inside the success function? That's wrong, along with the syntax!